# When to use cleanup() in Jython

Tags: java, jython, scripting-language, jython-2.7

Is it necessary to call `cleanup()` before `close()` in a `PythonInterpreter` in Jython every time?

I've been reading the docs, but I don't find much information about this function. The [javadocs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.python/jython-standalone/latest/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) don't say anything at all. The closest information I've found is [here, in readthedocs](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Concurrency/?highlight=cleanup), where they explain that a cleanup is necessary in some cases programming with threads, and I'm not even sure they refer to this particular function.

I wonder when I need to call `cleanup()`... and if the answer is always, then why would they make `cleanup()` and `close()` separate functions?

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but `cleanup()` is called from `close()`. See https://github.com/jython/jython/blob/master/src/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.java#L414.

Comment: Well, it's enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've been reading the Jython source code and doing some tests. Here is what I found:

**What `cleanup()` does**: It takes charge of the unhandeled resources, like running threads and files.

**What `cleanup()` doesn't**: Reset the state of the interpreter in any form; imported modules and defined variables are kept.

The following examples show this behavior:

#### Example 1

Let's import a module, define a variable and open a file.

```
PythonInterpreter py = new PythonInterpreter();

String code1 = "import sys;"
        + "a=45;"
        + "f = open('test.txt')";
String code2 = "print(sys.version_info);"
        + "print(a);"
        + "print(f.closed)";

// first execution
py.exec(code1);
py.exec(code2);

// second execution
py.cleanup();
py.exec(code2);

py.close()
```

It outputs

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
45
False
------
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
45
True
```

The module `sys` and the variables `a` and `f` still exist with the same values after the cleanup, but the open file is closed.

#### Example 2

For this, `func` is a slow function that takes aprox 2 seconds to complete (more than a normal `cleanup()`).

```
PythonInterpreter py = new PythonInterpreter();

String code3 = "from threading import Thread\n"
        + "def func():\n"
        + "  print 'th start'\n"
        + "  for i in range(0,20000000):\n"
        + "    x=i\n"
        + "  print 'th done'\n"
        + "th = Thread(target=func)\n"
        + "th.start()";
String code4 = "print th.isAlive()\n"
        + "th.join()";

// first execution
py.exec(code3);
py.exec(code4);
System.out.println("------");   

// second execution
py.exec(code3);
py.cleanup();
py.exec(code4);

py.close();
```

That outputs:

```
th start
True
th done
------
th start
th done
False
```

In the first execution, the main thread has plenty of time to check if `th` is alive and print it. In the second one, it always waits for `th` to finish, meaning that the `cleanup()` joins the thread somewhere.

#### Conclusion

As @mzjn pointed out, the `close()` function calls `cleanup()` and that makes sense, so **you never need to call `cleanup()` before `close()`**. The only case where you could need to call it manually would be if you wanted to continue using the `PythonInterpreter` but needed to close all open files and join all threads.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. What if I have an interpreter listening to all coming `interpreter.exec()` or `interpreter.eval()` requests? Do I need to periodically manually call `cleanup()`? I am conducting a load test where I can see for the same python code, the execution time is becoming slower and slower. And after a period of time, the execution time is getting better, and then slower again. But I can see the overall execution time is getting longer. I am thinking if the `cleanup()` can help or not?

Comment: If you are managing files and threads correctly in your code (closing and joining them, respectively) there would be no need, as far as I understand.

Comment: I am not managing files but just initializing instance and call the method. As far as I understand based on the Jython doc, I am able to directly use interpreter's own thread management to handle the coming `eval` or `exec` call (as the interpreter is thread safe): I have a pool to control how many requests are currently handled, but they are all using the same interpreter. Before you replied, I have tried to periodically call `cleanup()`, and it seems the memory consumption is more stable, and the execution time is more stable as well. But I might need more load test to see if it truly helps.

Comment: @Vision did you find a solution to yours, i see the same